# Family of subsets, understanding a specific definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Having a intro course to proofs. Question is regarding the specific definition below. 
The task is to show $\varepsilon$ is ideal, but I need to be certain of the definition first!

X is a non-empty set. Suppose x $\in$ X

$\varepsilon$ = $\{$ A $\subseteq$ X : x $\notin$ A $\}$

Is $\varepsilon$ = $\emptyset$??

Comment: No: $ \emptyset\in \varepsilon$

Comment: and now I understand why ;)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of examples might help:

1) Let $X = \{a,b\}$, $x = a$.  Then $\epsilon = \{\emptyset, \{ b \} \}$.  SUBSETS EXCLUDED ARE: $\{ a \}, \{ a, b \}$.

2) Let $X = \{ a, b, c \}$, $x = $a.  Then $\epsilon = \{ \emptyset, \{ b \}, \{ c \}, \{ b, c \} \}$.  SUBSETS EXCLUDED ARE: $\{ a \}, \{ a, b \}, \{ a, c \}, \{ a, b, c \}$.

Comment: An example made it clear, thank you!